# Dynamically build file name in Ant

Tags: ant

I have a requirement where I want to dynamically load property files into Ant. I have property files like deploy_DEV.properties, deploy_QA.properties, deploy_UAT.properties and so on. The current environment (i.e. dev, QA or UAT is passed in as a parameter). Based on this, I want to load the appropriate properties file. my code is as follows:

```
<for list="${deployEnvs}" param="site">
   <property file="${deploy_@{site}}"/>
</for>
```

However this fails to work. Is there any easy way to accomplish this. I also have access to ant-contrib if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `<for>` requires a `<sequential>` nested under it.

Second, the `${` in `${deploy_@{site}}` causes Ant to search for a property named `deploy_...`. Drop the surrounding `${` and `}` parts.

Third, the `.properties` file extension is missing.

Below are two property files and an Ant script that reads the property files and outputs their values.

### deploy_DEV.properties

```
key1=value1
```

### deploy_QA.properties

```
key2=value2
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-properties-files-with-for" default="run" basedir=".">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
    <target name="run">
        <property name="deployEnvs" value="DEV,QA"/>
        <for list="${deployEnvs}" param="site">
            <sequential>
                <property file="deploy_@{site}.properties"/>
            </sequential>
        </for>

        <echo>key1: ${key1}</echo>
        <echo>key2: ${key2}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Output

```
run:
     [echo] key1: value1
     [echo] key2: value2
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as well. I tested this using a <condition> and <available file=....> task. According to this, the file is not available.

Comment: @Neriyan: I've edited my answer. A `<sequential>` element is required under `<for>`. Further the `.properties` file extension is necessary.